# Oracle Data Access components 64 bit not working in IIS express 7.5

Tags: iis-express, odac

I have installed ODAC (Oracle data Access Components **64 bit**) odp.net 4. But unfortunately it does not work  with IIs Express. IIS express documentation says it supports both 32bit and 64bit systems. Is it possible that it can work with odp.net 4 (64 bit), or must we work with odac 32 bit components in development machines.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably too late now, but IIS Express 7.5 is 32-bit and cannot host a 64-bit process. I'm assuming that's what your problem is/was because I had a similar issue with the Oracle.DataAccess.dll. However, [IIS Express 8.0 Beta](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29055&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_all) can host your 64-bit site.

Visual Studio will only start the 32-bit IIS Express 8 process when you use it to start the site (F5 or Ctrl-F5). However, you can start the 64-bit process from the command line and then attach to the IIS Express process from Visual Studio, if you want to debug. The command I use is:

```
c:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe /site:SiteName
```

The the default IIS Express config file is in your documents folder at `IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`. That file contains the definitions for your sites and gives you the site name, which you can change.

Make sure you read the instructions for [Upgrading from IIS Express 7.5](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1286/iis-80-express-readme/).