# I am getting Oracle.DataAccess error in C#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

Error message is

```
  Could Not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, version=4.112.3.0, Culture=netural,
PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

May i know what is it solution?

Comment: try deleting the existing reference (in project References, delete Oracle.DataAccess) and then add the reference (right click project References and "Add Reference").

Comment: @tbone Ok sir i'm trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error indicates that you have not got the Oracle.DataAccess.Client.dll file on your machine.

The first thing to do is to check that it is present and that it is the correct version.

If it isn't there you can download and install ODAC (Oracle Data Access Components) for your machine. This should allow you to use the dll.

When you install the ODAC assemblies you will see by looking at your machine.config (for the given architecture you are using) and GAC that the dll has been installed successfully.

[ODAC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html)

EDIT: Given your added information try installing your ODAC on your IIS server. If this does not work then this topic may be of some help or at least give you another avenue to persue.

[ODAC on IIS 7.5 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412401/oracle-data-access-components-64-bit-not-working-in-iis-express-7-5)

Comment: have you ensured you have installed ODAC on the IIS server?

Comment: I have intalled ODAC. One application is already working but another instance of same application is encountering this error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Oracle Data Access Components for .NET.  See [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can Install Oracle Data Access in your machine

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html